# What would happen when you cast the spell Identify on a Genie Warlock's vessel?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock

As the title suggests: a Warlock with a pact to a genie in D&D 5e has someone cast *identify* on their genie's vessel.

What information would that person get?

Comment: Welcome to the stack, Xylar. Take the [tour] when you have a moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This GM would be conservative in what information [Identify](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/identify) can reveal.

Specifically, *identify* says:

> If it is a magic item or some other magic-imbued object, you learn its properties and how to use them, whether it requires attunement to use, and how many charges it has, if any. You learn whether any spells are affecting the item and what they are. If the item was created by a spell, you learn which spell created it.

The genie pact warlock's vessel says that it:

> Your patron gifts you a magical vessel that grants you a measure of the genie's power. The vessel is a Tiny object, and you can use it as a spellcasting focus for your warlock spells.
>
> ...
>
> While you are touching the vessel, you can use it in the following ways:
>
> **Bottled Respite.** As an action, you can magically vanish and enter your vessel, which remains in the space you left. The interior of the vessel is an extradimensional space .... While inside, you can hear the area around your vessel as if you were in its space. You can remain inside the vessel [for a few hours]. Any objects left in the vessel remain there until carried out, and if the vessel is destroyed, every object stored there harmlessly appears in the unoccupied spaces closest to the vessel's former space. ...
>
> **Genie's Wrath.** Once during each of your turns when you hit with an attack roll, you can deal extra damage to the target ... determined by [the patron's type].
>
> The vessel's [not quite trivial to destroy].

(Tasha's Cauldron of Everything, p 73-74, probably with some transcription typos)

So, rolling through *identify*:

1. Is the vessel "a magic item or some other magic-imbued object"? Yes, so we proceed.
2. What are the properties? The vessel is a spellcasting focus for genie-pact warlocks which they can use as an occasional extradimensional respite and to add damage to attacks.
3. Does it require attunement? No, but it can only be used by the warlock to whom it has been gifted.
4. Does it have charges? No.
5. Are any spells affecting the item? Not the base vessel, from its description; a specific vessel may, of course, have spells affecting it.
6. Was the item created by a spell? It's not specified one way or the other, though this GM would be reluctant to specify a single spell that could create a vessel - it diminishes the warlock's pact by making it easier (or even possible) for players to create a vessel without making a pact (or even without being warlocks).

This GM would definitely not include either the owning warlock nor the gifting genie among the vessel's properties, any more than I would include the owner or the crafter of a +1 sword among its properties. While the owner and gifter are facts about the vessel, I would be hard-pressed to call them properties. This is doubly so with spells like [Legend Lore](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/legend-lore), which exists to provide hints about the history of important items. As [an answer to a possibly-related question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/191967/20971) put it: "Identify would reveal that an axe is +3, but only Legend Lore would reveal that it's *The Axe of Dwarven Lords*".

Frankly, letting *identify* reveal the owner or the creator of a magic item is simply too powerful, especially for a 1st-level spell (even one with a costly material component).

Answer (score 2):

### You learn its properties

**RAW**

The vessel is a "magical vessel" and a "tiny object", so it qualifies as a "magic-imbued object" for [Identify](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/identify).  Thus the caster learns its properties: basically all of the text describing it on the page.

**Up to interpretation**

As a DM, I'd rule that which warlock it belongs to and which genie provided it falls under its properties, as well as whether the warlock is currently residing in it and whether it has any objects stored in it.

Warlock it belongs to may also fall under "how to use it" because to use it you must be that warlock. Learning the number of charges implies you learn about its magical state, so I think learning the Genie who owns it and if the warlock is inside seems reasonable.

A DM would be well within reason to not reveal this information. If your worried about a player casting this on your lamp, talk to your DM

**Other magic may intervene**

However, none of this information might be available if the vessel is under a spell like [Nondetect](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/nondetection) or, depending on interpretation, [Arcanist's Magic Aura](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/arcanists-magic-aura), which a clever DM or Warlock might use for story reasons.

Comment: Note that the question of whether *magic aura* defeats *identify* is a tricky one.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the owning warlock, providing genie, and current contents qualify as properties? ... and whether that extends to the contents of bags of holding or the owner of other magic items?

Comment: @minnmass I gave some more details, but as far as I know, what the properties of a magic item aren't defined in the rules, so its up to the DM.